# How to get \glsadd to work with sort=use?

Tags: glossaries, glossaries-extra

When I place an index reference in a line, e.g.

```
once upon a \index{time}midnight dreary,
```

the keyword ("time" in the example above) isn't typeset. However, when I place a glossary term in a line, e.g.

```
once upon a \gls{time}midnight dreary
```

the glossary replacement text typesets.

Can I make the glossary term behave like an index reference? I only want the glossary term to appear in the glossary listing in the end of the document, not when it is used in the document body.

MWE breaks with `glossaries` v4.34:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[automake,sort=use]{glossaries}

\makeglossaries
\newglossaryentry{potato}{name={potato},description={potato}}
\newglossaryentry{cucumber}{name={cucumber},description={cucumber}}
\newglossaryentry{onion}{name={onion},description={onion}}
\begin{document}
\glsadd{potato}tomato
\glsadd{cucumber}
\printglossaries
\end{document}
```

Also with `glossaries-extra` v1.23 if you replace `glossaries` with `glossaries-extra`.

Comment: @EvanAad: Your output is due to your usage of the `\printunsrtglossary` command, that, according to the documentation of `glossaries-extra` 'never sorts the entries and always lists all the defined entries for the given glossary'. If you use `\makeglossaries` in your preamble and `\printglossaries` in your document instead, the glossary only contains referenced entries in a sorted way.

Comment: @EvanAad: Your output tells you what to do. Try one of the listed steps and your edited MWE will work and give you the desired result.

Comment: @leandriis: I do not understand the output, and don't know what I should do. If you understand it, please write a working example as an answer to this question.

Comment: @Schweinebacke: Your solution does not work: page numbers don't display, and all the defined entries are listed, even if they're not used. Please remove the duplicate tag.

Comment: @Schweinebacke: The entries are ordered alphabetically (which is not what I want), and not according to their order of appearance in the document body (this is what I want).

Comment: @Schweinebacke: My question is only what's above the first separation line. Everything under it is my explanation why my question is not a duplicate and why the suggested solutions don't answer my question.

Comment: @Schweinebacke Yes, both should now be fixed with `glossaries-extra` v1.24 and `glossaries` v4.35.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**UPDATE:** In the lates versions `1.24` and `4.35` of `glossaries-extra` and `glossaries` respectively, the bug is fixed and the patch I have presented in this answer is no longer needed.

**UPDATE:** 
Since version `1.13` of `glossaries-extra` leads to the desired output shown in the image in this answer, the latest version `1.23` leads to potato and cucumber being written in the text as well (output is similar as if `\gls` was used instead of `\glsadd`.

I have therefore tried to adapt the solution to the `glossaries` package. This is shown in the following MWE, which leads to the desired output using version `4.29` as well as version `4.34`.

As the other example before, this MWE just needs to be compiled twice using `pdflatex`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[automake,sort=use]{glossaries}

\makeatletter
\renewrobustcmd*{\glsadd}[2][]{%
  \@gls@adjustmode
  \glsdoifexists{#2}%
  {%
    \def\@glsnumberformat{glsnumberformat}%
    \edef\@gls@counter{\csname glo@\glsdetoklabel{#2}@counter\endcsname}%
    \setkeys{glossadd}{#1}%
    \@gls@saveentrycounter%
    \@gls@setsort{#2}%
    \@@do@wrglossary{#2}%
  }%
}
\makeatother

\newglossaryentry{potato}{name={potato},description={potato}}
\newglossaryentry{cucumber}{name={cucumber},description={cucumber}}
\newglossaryentry{onion}{name={onion},description={onion}}
\makeglossaries
\begin{document}
\glsadd{potato}tomato
\glsadd{cucumber}
\printglossaries
\end{document}
```

---

### **older answer using the `glossaries-extra` package**

Since I initially seemed to have misunderstood the desired output (sorry for that), here is a corrected version of the MWE, that only prints entries that were used by `\glsadd`. Additionally, the glossary is sorted by appearance instead of being sorted alphabetically.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[automake,sort=use]{glossaries-extra}

\makeatletter
\renewrobustcmd*{\glsadd}[2][]{%
  \@gls@adjustmode
  \@glsxtr@record{#1}{#2}%
  \glsdoifexists{#2}%
  {%
    \def\@glsnumberformat{glsnumberformat}%
    \edef\@gls@counter{\csname glo@\glsdetoklabel{#2}@counter\endcsname}%
    \setkeys{glossadd}{#1}%
    \@gls@saveentrycounter
    \@gls@setsort{#2}%
    \@@do@wrglossary{#2}%
  }%
}
\makeatother

\newglossaryentry{potato}{name={potato},description={potato}}
\newglossaryentry{cucumber}{name={cucumber},description={cucumber}}
\newglossaryentry{onion}{name={onion},description={onion}}
\makeglossaries
\begin{document}
\glsadd{potato}tomato
\glsadd{cucumber}
\printglossaries
\end{document}
```

[image]

As you can see in the image of the output, 'potato' and 'cucumber' are not printed in the text, but appear in the glossary in the order, they were used in the code (option `sort=use`). Additionally, 'onion' does not show up in the glossary, as it was not used in a `\glsadd` command.

In this example I am using the `\makeglossaries` command and a bugfix that was suggested by Nicola Talbot in the comments. As stated by her, the bug will be fixed in the upcoming version, so with future versions, the whole code between `\makeatletter`and `\makeatother` will not be needed any more.

This solution also requires a sorting program, so I included the `automake` option. For alternatives, please see my original answer below.

---

**Old answer:**
The following lines are my original answer. Although it is not needed to achieve the output Evan Aad is looking for, I will leave it here to not make the comments on this answer seem out of context.

The following MWE should give you the desired output:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[automake]{glossaries-extra}
\newglossaryentry{potato}{name={potato},description={potato}}
\newglossaryentry{cucumber}{name={cucumber},description={cucumber}}
\makeglossaries
\begin{document}
\glsadd{cucumber}cucumber
\par
\glsadd{potato}tomato
\printglossaries
\end{document}
```

Please note, that I have added the option `automake` to the `glossaries-extra` package. This will automatically run `makeindex` or `xindy` for you. These then sort the cited references alphabetically.

You can alternatively run the application `makeglossaries` yourself through the command line or add a custom entry to your editor. 
Please note, that since this application is written in perl, you will need an appropriate perl-interpreter.

Additionally, you can es well choose to run the lua application `makeglossaries-lite.lua` through the command line or by configuring your editor.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't want the entries sorted alphabetically; otherwise, I would have used an index. I want the entries sorted in the order in which the references appear in the document body.

Comment: @EvanAad Then use `sort=use` in the package options.

Comment: Actually the `automake` option doesn't use `makeglossaries` (which isn't on the restricted list). It explicitly runs `makeindex` (which is a trusted application) or `xindy`. That way it can at least run in restricted mode if you're using `makeindex`.

Comment: @NicolaTalbot: This option does not seem to work when used in addition with `\glsadd`.

Comment: @NicolaTalbot: If I add `,sort=use` after the `automake` option in the above example, I get an error message.

Comment: @leandriis Hmm, that's strange. I'll have to investigate. Perhaps switch to `\makenoidxglossaries` since no sorting is required.

Comment: @leandriis Found the problem. `\glsadd` is missing `\@gls@setsort{#2}`. It will be fixed in the next version of `glossaries` (v4.35).

Comment: I tried your new code, but I don't get the same output as you. What I get is [this](https://imgur.com/a/C8hLU).

Comment: @EvanAad: Sorry for all this confusion. I have edited my answer again to include a bug fix that was suggested by Nicola Talbot. I hope, the MWE now works for you.

Comment: @leandriis You need to move `\@gls@setsort{#2}` up a line (just before `\@@do@wrglossary`).

Comment: @leandriis: Thanks for your persistence. I appreciate it and hope that with your help this problem will be solved at some point. However, I tried your code, and I get [this](https://imgur.com/a/jHHAn), which is not good, because only "tomato" should be typeset in the document body.

Comment: @NicolaTalbot: Thanks for pointing this out. I have corrected the MWE accordingly. As you refered to updating the `glossaries` package, please also keep in mind, that this bug is also contained in the `glossaries-extra` package, that I used in the example.

Comment: The output to your latest attempt is [this](https://imgur.com/a/DH9Ng), which is not good, since only "tomato" should be typeset in the document body.

Comment: @leandriis Yes, I noticed that when looking at your patch. (I had forgotten!) I'll get both packages fixed.

Comment: @EvanAad: I have tried to recreate the output you show with the example I have posted, but I'm unfortunately not able to. I can only get your output (with potato and cucumber printed  in the text) if I use `\gls` instead of `\glsadd`. So please make sure, you used `\glsasdd`.

Comment: @leandriis: I copied-and-pasted your code to the file `test.tex`, then I executed from the command line 1. `pdflatex test`, 2. `makeglossaries test`, 3. `pdflatex test`.

Comment: @EvanAad: First of all, yo do not need to run `makeglossaries` explicitly, as the MWE includes the `automake` option. So in general, it is sufficient to run `pdflatex test` twice. I nevertheless tried your approach and always end up with the output, that I posted in the answer.

Comment: @EvanAad: I have now tried to reproduce your output with the latest version of `glossaries-extra` that is available at CTAN (version `1.23`) and I am now able to recreate your output. However, using version `1.13`, that I was using to create my answer, I get the desired result.

Comment: @NicolaTalbot: It seems, as if my MWE works with version 1.13 of glossaries-extra, while version 1.23 leads to an output similar to the usage of `\gls` instead of `\glsadd`. Were there any changes inbetween, that can explain this different behaviour?

Comment: @EvanAad: I have now added another update to my answer. Instead of using the `glossaries-extra` package, I switched to the `glossaries` package, that does not produce the undesired output that you encountered using the latest version of the package. Hopefully this helps you.

Comment: Thanks. This helps a lot. However, I wish (1) it worked with `glossaries-extra`, (2) it worked out-of-the-box, without your clever fix. At any rate, great job!

Comment: @leandriis Yes, the introduction of the `record` option changed the indexing, which is why `glossaries-extra` redefines `\glsadd`.

Comment: @EvanAad Give me a chance, I can't do instantaneous updates! The new versions should be available in the next day or so.

Comment: Problem now fixed in both `glossaries.sty` v4.35 and `glossaries-extra.sty` v1.24. Be careful with the `glossaries-extra` patch. The internal command `\@glsxtr@record` now has three arguments.

Comment: @NicolaTalbot: Thank you very much. What do you mean by "Be careful with the `glossaries-extra` patch"? In what way should I be careful?

Comment: @EvanAad It will work with some versions but not others. The simplest thing is to upgrade to the new version of `glossaries-extra` then you won't need the patch.